# Java nested loop logic error

Tags: java, logic, nested-loops

I want to know what is wrong with my logic when my output is supposed to be as follows:

There are two arrays of integers and that prints the index of the first occurrence of the first list in the second list.For example, suppose that you have these arrays:

```
int[] list1 = {1, 3, 6};
int[] list2 = {1, 3, 5, 8, 12, 1, 3, 17, 1, 3, 6, 9, 1, 3, 6};
```

Then the call `indexOf(list1, list2)` should return 8 because the sequence of values stored in `list1` appears in `list2` starting at index 8. The `list1` appears twice in `list2`, starting at position 8 and starting at position 12. The method should return the first such position.

Currently, my code does not print anything...

```
public static void indexOf(int[] arr1, int[] arr2){

    for(int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++){
            if(arr1[j] != arr2[i]){
                break; 
            }
            if(j == arr1.length -1){
                System.out.println(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arr1[j] != arr2[i]` should be `arr1[j] != arr2[i + j]`

**Why**

In each iteration of the inner loop you should be comparing each element of the original subsequence (`arr1[j]`) with the corresponding element in the current subsequence you have sliced from `arr2` (`arr2[i + j]`). You were comparing to just the first element in the current slice.

**Moreover**

Your loop termination condition should be `i + (arr1.length - 1) < arr2.length` to avoid accessing out of bound index if the last element in `arr2` was 1 (or in general equal to the first element in `arr1`).

**...also**

The second `break` should be `return` to print the first occurrence as you stated.

**Full Code**

```
public static void indexOf(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {

    for(int i = 0; i + (arr1.length - 1) < arr2.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
            if(arr1[j] != arr2[i + j]) {
                break; 
            }
            if(j == (arr1.length - 1)){
                System.out.println(i);
                break; // break to print all the occurrences. return to print only the first.
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on where I need to ad the loop termination condition? Also why should my second break be return? I thought it doesn't matter whether its a break or return, since I'm printing as I'm going through the code, not somewhere else...

Comment: In the outer loop change `for(int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++)` to `for(int i = 0; i + (arr1.length - 1) < arr2.length; i++)`. I understood from your description that you want to print the index of the first match (You wrote *"The method should return the first such position"*).

Answer (score 0):

This works (I added i+j instead of j):

```
   public static void indexOf(int[] arr1, int[] arr2){

    for(int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++){
            if((i + j) < arr2.length && arr1[j] != arr2[i + j]){
                break; 
            }
            if(j == arr1.length -1){
                System.out.println(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```